# Windows Server 2022 Security Center Issue

Tags: windows, security, windows-server

So I'm using Windows Server 2022 DC as desktop on my laptop, the build is 20348. What I encountered is that Windows Security Center is working abnormally, It stuck when startup and automatically exit after a few second.

I checked the local services, and I found out that Service "Windows Security Center" don't even exist, but although the dashboard cannot be accessed, the service itself seem to be running - When I start XMRig it remove it and prompt threat.

Is there any way fixing it?

sfc command doesnt help

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved!

Execute with privilige in PowerShell

> Add-AppxPackage -Register -DisableDevelopmentMode "C:\Windows\SystemApps\Microsoft.Windows.SecHealthUI_cw5n1h2txyewy\AppXManifest.xml"